# Check PageRank Through XML

Tags: php, xml, pagerank

I've searched this website and googled alot but unfortunately didn't find any real answer so please pardon me if it doesn't makes sense.

I'm using PHP to check page rank of a given URL, but it sometimes show error due to busy google website (http://toolbarqueries.google.com) The error it shows is;
[image]

Is there any way I can check page rank through either XML or even PHP with a better solution, which doesn't show any error like that?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've searched and find a great solution. try this:

```
class GooglePageRankChecker {

  // Track the instance
  private static $instance;

  // Constructor
  function getRank($page) {
    // Create the instance, if one isn't created yet
    if(!isset(self::$instance)) {
      self::$instance = new self();
    }
    // Return the result
    return self::$instance->check($page);
  }

  // Convert string to a number
  function stringToNumber($string,$check,$magic) {
    $int32 = 4294967296;  // 2^32
      $length = strlen($string);
      for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
          $check *= $magic;
          //If the float is beyond the boundaries of integer (usually +/- 2.15e+9 = 2^31),
          //  the result of converting to integer is undefined
          //  refer to http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php
          if($check >= $int32) {
              $check = ($check - $int32 * (int) ($check / $int32));
              //if the check less than -2^31
              $check = ($check < -($int32 / 2)) ? ($check + $int32) : $check;
          }
          $check += ord($string{$i});
      }
      return $check;
  }

  // Create a url hash
  function createHash($string) {
    $check1 = $this->stringToNumber($string, 0x1505, 0x21);
      $check2 = $this->stringToNumber($string, 0, 0x1003F);

    $factor = 4;
    $halfFactor = $factor/2;

      $check1 >>= $halfFactor;
      $check1 = (($check1 >> $factor) & 0x3FFFFC0 ) | ($check1 & 0x3F);
      $check1 = (($check1 >> $factor) & 0x3FFC00 ) | ($check1 & 0x3FF);
      $check1 = (($check1 >> $factor) & 0x3C000 ) | ($check1 & 0x3FFF);  

      $calc1 = (((($check1 & 0x3C0) << $factor) | ($check1 & 0x3C)) << $halfFactor ) | ($check2 & 0xF0F );
      $calc2 = (((($check1 & 0xFFFFC000) << $factor) | ($check1 & 0x3C00)) << 0xA) | ($check2 & 0xF0F0000 );

      return ($calc1 | $calc2);
  }

  // Create checksum for hash
  function checkHash($hashNumber)
  {
      $check = 0;
    $flag = 0;

    $hashString = sprintf('%u', $hashNumber) ;
    $length = strlen($hashString);

    for ($i = $length - 1;  $i >= 0;  $i --) {
      $r = $hashString{$i};
      if(1 === ($flag % 2)) {
        $r += $r;
        $r = (int)($r / 10) + ($r % 10);
      }
      $check += $r;
      $flag ++;
    }

    $check %= 10;
    if(0 !== $check) {
      $check = 10 - $check;
      if(1 === ($flag % 2) ) {
        if(1 === ($check % 2)) {
          $check += 9;
        }
        $check >>= 1;
      }
    }

    return '7'.$check.$hashString;
  }

  function check($page) {

    // Open a socket to the toolbarqueries address, used by Google Toolbar
    $socket = fsockopen("toolbarqueries.google.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    // If a connection can be established
    if($socket) {
      // Prep socket headers
      $out = "GET /tbr?client=navclient-auto&ch=".$this->checkHash($this->createHash($page)).
              "&features=Rank&q=info:".$page."&num=100&filter=0 HTTP/1.1\r\n";
      $out .= "Host: toolbarqueries.google.com\r\n";
      $out .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; GoogleToolbar 2.0.114-big; Windows XP 5.1)\r\n";
      $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

      // Write settings to the socket
      fwrite($socket, $out);

      // When a response is received...
      $result = "";
      while(!feof($socket)) {
        $data = fgets($socket, 128);
        $pos = strpos($data, "Rank_");
        if($pos !== false){
          $pagerank = substr($data, $pos + 9);
          $result += $pagerank;
        }
      }
      // Close the connection
      fclose($socket);

      // Return the rank!
      return $result;
    }
  }
}
```

Now where you want to check the PR, use this code `$some_var = GooglePageRankChecker::getRank("http://khanqah-daruslam.com");`

Replace URL to yours (or any custom URL)

Comment: A very nice solution, Omer. It is less weakness compared to other classes I found.

Answer (score 1):

Try SEOstats: https://github.com/eyecatchup/SEOstats

> SEOstats is a powerful open source PHP library to request a bunch of
>   SEO relevant metrics such as detailed backlink analyses, keyword and
>   traffic statistics, website trends, page authority, the Google
>   Pagerank, the Alexa Trafficrank and much more.

Comment: Thanks but I already saw this and do not want to use any heavy library. I want a light weight PHP or XML code.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: try this then: http://blogbl.com/google-pr-checker-script-to-check-pr-of-all-pages-within-website/

Answer (score -1):

> Try SEOstats: https://github.com/eyecatchup/SEOstats
>
> > Thanks but I already saw this and do not want to use any heavy library. I want a light weight PHP or XML code. Thanks anyway!

Actually you don't need to use the full library. SEOstats' Google PageRank method uses a standalone class that can be used as follows:

```
<?php
  $url = 'http://somedomain.com/';  
  $pr  = new GTB_PageRank($url);

  $rank = $pr->getPageRank();

  printf("The Google Pagerank of %s is %s.", $url, $rank);
```

The nice thing about this class, as I think, is that it supports all existing PageRank hashing algorithms (awesome, jenkins, jenkins2 and IE) and has some advanced features built in, such as suggested Toolbar-TLD and more.

You can check it out here:
https://github.com/eyecatchup/SEOstats/blob/master/SEOstats/Services/3rdparty/GTB_PageRank.php

Comment: @ the one who just downvoted this answer: you should make a statement as for why! Cause, as far as I can see, you either did not understood the question or did not read my answer correctly. Otherwise it doesn't make sense to downvote my answer but not also downvote kovach's answer at the same time. Any statement?