# php - If Pagerank Is Less Than 0 Output N/A

Tags: php, variables, pagerank

I am using a class from Imran Omer on this thread [Check PageRank Through XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932740/check-pagerank-through-xml) to get pagerank.

It is working great. The only problem I got here is I couldn't get the blank value. What I get is `0` is equal to `''`.

**Here is what I mean:**

Let's assume that `domain.com` PR is `blank` or `no value`, `example.com` PR is `0` and `yoursite.com` is `1`.

With the `class` I mentioned above, I want to retrieve their `pagerank` and output string `N/A` if the `pagerank` is not `0`, `1` or bigger.

So, the code would be something like this:

```
$allurls = array('domain.com', 'example.com', 'yoursite.com');

foreach( $allurls as $url) {

$pr = GooglePageRankChecker::getRank($url);

if ($pr >= 0) {
echo $pr . ' ';
} else {
echo "N/A";
}

}
```

But it returns just like this:

`0 1` instead of `N/A 0 1`

I had tried `empty` and `is_null`, but it still can not recognize the `blank` value.

How to make it recognize `blank` value and not confuse it with `0` so I can output 'N/A' when the pagerank is blank?

Best Regards

Comment: Have you checked, what exactly is returned by the `GooglePageRankChecker` method in that case? Using `var_dump()` for example.

Comment: have you tried `if (trim($pr) != '')` ? If that is not working you should check what exactly ::getRank() returns.

Comment: @Sirko Not yet Sirko.

Comment: @MarkS Not yet MarkS, Would you like to provide it as an answer so I can accept it? It work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your class `$result` is by default set:

```
$result = "";
```

So you should check your condidtion like this:

```
if (trim($pr) != '')
```

Note - `trim` is just to make sure there is no whitespace, should work even without it.

Answer as requested in comment.